# Change Visual Studio "Current regional settings" value

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I'm designing some SSRS reports in Visual Studio and every datetime field is displaying as MM/dd/yyy instead of my preference of dd/MM/yyyy

My Windows regional settings are English(Ireland) but if I look at any datetmie placeholder propery window it shows "Current regional settings: English (United States)".
I don't know where it's picking this up from (pretty certain it's not the SQL login defined in the dataset either) or how to change it. Any ideas?

(I could forcibly change the output of every datetime field to my preferred format would would like to not have to do this every time and instead just get the environment into the right regional setting)

*Update: Forgot to add, I can see a Language tag in the RDL which is set to "en-US" and whenever I try to change that to anything else and save it automatically changes back to "en-US"*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Each report has its own regional settings.

Click on a part of your reporting design surface that has no objects and look at the Properties window for the report. Under `Localization` there is a setting called `Language` which defaults to `English (United States)` or `en-US`. You could set this to your own regional settings but I like to set it to `=User!Language` so that it displays in the regional settings preferences of the user.

Comment: Cheers. Changing it in the properties window seemed to hold (don't know why it wouldn't let me do so directly in the RDL file). Out of curiosity, is it always defaulted to en-US no matter what? Or can I change a setting somewhere in VisualStudio so it will default to something else?

Comment: I think it is always `en-US`. I have a couple of blank template reports that I copy when creating reports; these contain regional settings, header, footers, margins, page size, etc, so I have my base level settings to start with (or just copy an existing repot and edit from there).

Answer (score 5):

Further to Chris' correct answer - In BIDS for VS 2012 a right-click on the design surface didn't show a localization screen. Hit f7 to edit the underlying code of the report where you can find the appropriate node and change it to your local setting:

```
      ....</ReportSections>
      <Language>en-GB</Language>
      ...
  </Report>
```

Comment: On my VS2012 F7 didn't work, but right-click the RDL file in solution explorer has an edit-code option.

Comment: Chris's answer was about the standard properties window in VS once you've selected the report object, rather than a localization screen- so just look there rather than needing to edit the underlying code.

Comment: I was not able to do it Chris via the report properties, I had to F7 and update it this way

Comment: That does not work for me using VS 2017 and SSRS 2017.       
  Deserialization failed: The element 'ReportSection' in namespace has invalid child element 'Language' in namespace

Comment: I also couldn't find it at first, but it appears to be a little bit hidden in the menus. You just click outside the main design surface area, then underneath properties there is a small downward triangle. If you click on said triangle and then look for 'report' you should be able to find it after you've selected it.

Answer (score 3):

The right solution is the one from Chris, but as you have wrote the update, you can try to modify the expression formula of your placeholder in this way:

`=Format(Fields!FieldName.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Answer from Chris did the job but would have had to use expression formula had it not. Fine for one field or a simple report, but once they get more complicated it's not something I want to have to keep track of!

Comment: While this seems to solve the problem, it has other implications; for example, exporting to Excel would now export this field as Text rather than Date making sorting problematic. Presentation should always be decoupled from data. A better way (if not changing the Language setting) would be to keep the cell value as `Fields!FieldName.Value` and change the `Format` property to `dd/MM/yyyy` - this way the data type remains Date but displays the way you want.